# C++ shuffle algorithms

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

I have an assignment where I must create a random shuffle algorithm using rand() or another random number generator. I cannot use the built in std::shuffle algorithm, nor can I use Fisher-Yates. Are there any lesser-known shuffle algorithms that I can implement?

Complexity and speed are not too important to me with this specific project, so if there is a shuffle algorithm that works well but has a sucky complexity that is completely fine with me.

Thank you!

Comment: Swap every element in your container with a randomly-chosen element in your container.  That's a simple, full shuffle algorithm.

Comment: Assuming that you have a perfect random number generator which generates numbers with equal probability in the desired range (which `rand()` does not do), does the probability of every possible permutation have to be equal?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel they do not have to be equal. As long as a previously ordered vector is completely shuffled, that should do.

Comment: @DrewDormann Forgive me if this sounds dumb, but isn't that the Fisher-Yates algorithm?

Comment: @Hannah no, that's not dumb.  Fisher-Yates seems to be a name given to that algorithm.  I've now learned this.

Comment: @DrewDormann: What you describe is not Fisher-Yates. You are describing a biased shuffling algorithm, whereas Fisher-Yates is unbiased. See [this blog article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) for further information. Fun fact: That article was written by Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of Stack Overflow, one year before he founded it.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
template<typename DType>
struct Shufflable
{
      DType data;
      int random;
};

std::vector<Shufflable<float>> vec;
...init vec from input float data array...
// give random values to them
for(auto & v:vec)
    v.random = your_mersenne_twister_random_generator(); // std::mt19937

// shuffle
std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](auto & e1, auto & e2){ return e1.random<e2.random;});
... copy float datas to original array from vec ...
```

assign random numbers to each element, then sort them on those random values.

If the duplicated random numbers' bias is a problem, you can improve the sorting by using the data too, or even applying a second-pass for randomization for all of the duplicates.

Comment: This algorithm is biased if the same random number is generated for two different elements. However, OP did not ask for an unbiased algorithm, so I am upvoting the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information about bias. Maybe same random numbers should've further compared using the data values & secondary randomization too.